# Can I return an Array with a method applied on one line?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why these behave differently and what exactly is going on with the second example?

I am trying to return an array with an item pushed to it.  I have the correct answer in the first example but I don't understand what is going on in the second version that it is returning the length instead of the array?

I was hoping someone could provide some insight to what's going on with this second example?

```js
// I'm trying to return a new array with the added item. 

var myArray1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
var myArray2 = ["one", "two", "three"];
var myExtraItem = "four";

// First Example producing desired result. 
function addToList1(someArray, someItem){
  someArray.push(someItem);
  return someArray;
}

console.log(addToList1(myArray1, myExtraItem)); // returns ["one", "two", "three","four"]

// Second Example listing # of items in array. 
function addToList2(someArray, someItem) {
  return someArray.push(someItem);
}

console.log(addToList2(myArray2, myExtraItem)); // returns 4
```

Comment: You’re returning the return value of `.push()`; `Array`’s `push` returns the new length of the array.

Comment: addToList2 return someArray.push(someItem); > return the array but the old not with the new value.and the first example addToList1 first push and after return the array with the new value too,

Comment: push method return number of element in array and not the array, that is why you are getting a number and not full array.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are adding the entry to the array and then returning that array. In the second case you are returning the length of the array as documented here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

The return of push to an array in JavaScript is the length of the array. From MDN "The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array."

Answer (score 0):

The [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method adds an item to the array and then returns the new length.

Your second example returns directly from the `.push()` call so the length is returned.

While your first example first push an item to the array, then return the array itself.